# imagemagick - compare two JPEGs with masking image

Tags: compare, imagemagick

I want to compare two JPG images. I know the parameter "fuzz" because of JPG compensation.
Now I want to compare these two images with a mask - I dont want to compare the whole rectangle, only a part of it.
As a result I want the pixel difference to calculate the percentage difference and in step two I want an image, which shows the difference in red/black.

I found this article: [New compare feature](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=31053)

My old way (compare the whole rectangle):

```
/usr/bin/compare -metric ae /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/15.jpg /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/14.jpg -compose src /dev/null 2>&1
=> 8432 Pixels different
```

My old way (compare the whole rectangle and paint it to an image):

```
/usr/bin/compare -metric ae /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/15.jpg /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/14.jpg -compose src /dev/null -highlight-color Red -lowlight-color Black /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/diff.gif
```

My new try (compare the images with a masking image):

```
/usr/bin/compare -read-mask /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/mask.png -metric ae /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/15.jpg /mnt/usbstorage/tmp/14.jpg -compose src /dev/null 2>&1
=> 8432 Pixels different
```

The different pixels won't change! 8432 <=> 8432...so my mask doesn't change anything!

When I do that command to save the difference in a new image there are gray places for the mask, black places for non-changed-pixels and red areas for different pixels -> perfect. The image is perfect, the pixel comparison stays the same. Why?

I don't get it - do you have an explanation / example? Am I doing anything wrong?

Here are the files:

[image: 14.jpg]

[image: 15.jpg]

[image: mask.png]

Answer (score 0):

Masked compare only works in IM 7.0.3.9 or higher. In IM 7, you must add magick before compare:

```
magick compare -metric rmse -read-mask mask.png 14.jpg 15.jpg 14_15_diff.png
```

[image]

The red areas are where they differ under the mask. The white areas are where they are the same under the mask. The gray areas are outside the mask.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the read-mask is not being applied to the `Absolute Error` metric.

Comment: It should be. But it only should work in IM 7. He is using IM 6.

Comment: Correct,with metric ae there ist no difference with masking. Only with rmse

Comment: AE only counts differences. RMSE computes the root mean squared error which includes 0 for no differences between pixels. AE should give different counts if the mask contains some differences but not all differences.